# How to solve these exponential equations for D?

Tags: exponentiation, closed-form

I'm curious if this is even possible to solve for *D*.  *D* is the only variable, *x*, *y*, *z*, and *w* are all constants, and *e* is the mathematical constant e.

$$ (\frac{x+yD^{2}}{zD})^{\sqrt{2D}} = e^{\sqrt{w}} $$

Comment: I'm also not sure which tags this falls under, so any suggestions of that would be great too.

Comment: I am nearly sure that there will not be a *closed form* ("formula") for the solution. Numerical methods are always available, and you may be able to find a formula that gives a good approximation for values of $D$ near a certain value.